# Angular JS 1.1: Using a shared angular module with ng-include

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am learning angular js while I am working on a project. I have a simple search box that I am using as a shared component on all my pages. The search box has its own controller and service that perform ajax calls to server to give suggestions on key press. It all works perfectly if I run the searchBox.html. However if I use it in anonymousHomePage.html using ng-include. It does not seem to work the control does not even come to the searchBoxController.js and no suggestions appear. Plus I see the below error when anonymousHomePage.html loads.

```
Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: $compileProvider from ngAnimate
at <anonymous>:2765:19
at Object.getService [as get] (<anonymous>:2891:39)
at <anonymous>:2843:45
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at forEach (<anonymous>:148:11)
at loadModules (<anonymous>:2833:5)
at <anonymous>:2838:38
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at forEach (<anonymous>:148:11)
at loadModules (<anonymous>:2833:5)
```

Please help as I am really stuck. Really sorry for the long question but I don't know how else to ask this. The Contents of my files below:

anonymousHomePage.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
       <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <link rel = "stylesheet"
         href = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.css">
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.js"></script>
       <script src="/BookBox/components/anonymousHomePage/anonymousHomePageService.js"></script>
       <script src="/BookBox/components/anonymousHomePage/anonymousHomePageController.js"></script>
       <script src="/BookBox/shared/searchBox/searchBoxService.js"></script>
      <script src="/BookBox/shared/searchBox/searchBoxController.js"></script>
      <style>

      </style>

    </head>
    <body ng-app="anonymousHomePageCtrl" ng-controller="anonymousHomeCtrl">
        <ng-include src="'/BookBox/shared/anonymousToolbar/anonymousToolbar.html'"></ng-include>
        <ng-include src="'/BookBox/shared/searchBox/searchBox.html'"></ng-include>
    </body>
</html>
```

anonymousHomePageController.js:

```
 var anonymousHomePageController=angular.module("anonymousHomePageCtrl", 
 ["ngAnimate","anonymousHomePageService","searchBoxCtrlModule","searchBoxServiceModule"])
    .controller("anonymousHomeCtrl", function($scope,anonymousService){
        $scope.userInfo;
        $scope.getUserInfo=function(){debugger;
            anonymousService.getAnonymousUserInfo().
            success(function (users) {debugger
            $scope.userInfo = users;
             })
            .error(function (error) {
                 alert(error);
        });


        }
        //$scope.getUserInfo();

    });
```

searchBox.html:

```
<html>
    <head>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <link rel = "stylesheet"
         href = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.css">
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.js"></script>
      <script src="/BookBox/shared/searchBox/searchBoxService.js"></script>
      <script src="/BookBox/shared/searchBox/searchBoxController.js"></script>

      <style>

      </style>

    </head>
    <body ng-app="searchBoxCtrlModule" ng-controller="searchBoxCtrl">
        <div class='d-flex justify-content-center'>
         <div class="row" > 
          <md-select ng-style="{'height':'42px','border':'1px solid #CCCCCC','background':'#f2f2f2'}" ng-model="selectedType" placeholder="Type" required md-no-asterisk="false"
                      md-on-close="setSelectedType(selectedType)">
          <md-option value="Title">Title</md-option>
          <md-option value="Author">Author</md-option>
          <md-option value="Publisher">Publisher</md-option>
        </md-select>     
        <div ng-style="{'width':'600px','margin-top':'20px'}">

      <!-- <form name="autocompleteForm"> -->
        <md-autocomplete

                  md-menu-class="decreaseWidth"
                  ng-disabled = "false"
                  md-no-cache = "true"
                  md-selected-item = "selectedItem"

                  md-search-text = "searchText"
                  md-items = "item in getSearchResults(searchText)"
                  md-item-text = "item.title"
                  md-min-length = "4"
                  placeholder = "Type to search">

                  <md-item-template>
                     <span md-highlight-text = "searchText"
                        md-highlight-flags = "^i">{{item.title}}</span>
                  </md-item-template>

                  <md-not-found>
                     No Books matching "{{searchText}}" were found.

                  </md-not-found>
               </md-autocomplete>

       <!--</form> -->
        </div>
             <a class="btn btn-success" ng-style={'margin-top':'20px','height':'42px'} href="#" role="button"><img src="/BookBox/assets/img/open-iconic/svg/magnifying-glass.svg" height="15"></a>
        </div> 
       </div>     
    </body>
</html>
```

searchBoxController.js:

```
var searchBoxCtrlModule=angular.module("searchBoxCtrlModule",['ngMaterial','searchBoxServiceModule'])
    .controller("searchBoxCtrl", function($scope,$timeout,$q,searchBoxService){
        $scope.searchText;
        $scope.searchResult=[];
        $scope.selectedItem;
        $scope.selectedType='None';


        $scope.getSearchResults=function(searchText){debugger;
            if(searchText.length >= 4){
            $scope.searchResult.length=0;         
            searchBoxService.getSearchSuggestions(searchText,$scope.selectedType).
            success(function (books) {debugger
            $scope.searchResult = books;
             })
            .error(function (error) {
                 alert(error);
        });
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $timeout(function () { deferred.resolve( $scope.searchResult ); }, Math.random() * 1000, false);
        return deferred.promise;
    }
   }

 })
```

searchBoxService.js:

```
var searchBoxServiceModule=angular.module("searchBoxServiceModule",[])
    .service("searchBoxService", function($http){
        var searchBoxService={};
       searchBoxService.getSearchSuggestions=function(key, searchType){
           return $http.get("http://localhost:8081/BookBoxAPI/actions/search/"+key+"/"+searchType);
       }
       return searchBoxService;
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to angular version incompatibility
so can you please replace the script with the following scripts

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Nattamai for your reply. Can you please point me to the html file I need to add these scripts to?